# Logarithmic Laplace transform of the uniform measure on a convex set

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-geometry

This question comes from a lemma (whose proof is left as an exercise) which I came across when reading the continuous exponential-weighting algorithm.

Let $\mathcal K\subset\mathbb R^d$ be a compact convex set with finite volume: $|\mathcal K|<\infty$. Let $u\in\mathbb R^d$ be a fixed vector and define $x^*\in\arg\min_{x\in\mathcal K}\langle x, u\rangle$. Prove that
$$
-\log\left(\frac{1}{|\mathcal K|}\int_{\mathcal K}e^{-\langle x-x^*, u\rangle}dx\right)\leq 1+\max\left(0, d\log\left(\sup_{x,y\in\mathcal K}\langle x-y, u\rangle\right)\right).
$$

Can someone give me some hint how to prove this inequality? I feel confused how $d$ appears in the bound. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.